# Do different 68k simulators have different TRAP tasks?

Tags: assembly, 68000

I've been revisiting Motorola 68000 programming lately. Admittedly, when I took the course I just did what was necessary to pass (and had a horrible professor)...but NOW I'm actually interested in the stuff. Anyway, looking through my old textbook [The 68000 Microprocessor by James L. Antonakos](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130195618), he uses the following code:

```
      ORG     $8000
HMSG  DC.B    'Hello!'
      DC.B    0  
      ORG     #8100  
START MOVEA.L #HMSG,A3  
      TRAP    #3  
      TRAP    #9  
      END     START
```

This would not compile in [Easy68k](http://www.easy68k.com/), but the book has [ASM68K referenced](https://web.sunybroome.edu/~antonakos_j/68kug.htm). When I changed the code to this, it worked.

```
      ORG   $1000
HSMG  DC.B  'Hello!',0

START LEA   HSMG,A1
      MOVE  #14,D0  
      TRAP  #15

END START
```

Is this just due to differences between the compilers? Or am I missing something bigger here? I understand that in the simulator `TRAP #15` executes whatever task is in register D0 at the time, but are there different trap tasks per simulator, or is that standard across all 68000 processors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `TRAP` instruction just calls a routine that's pointed to by a longword somewhere in memory. That part of the behaviour is common to all 68000 CPUs. Where that longword points, and what the routine it points to does (and therefore how you pass it the data it needs and so on) depends on the particular system.

(The Atari ST for example used `TRAP` to call into the OS, and you generally passed all relevant information on the stack. The register contents were ignored. I believe Mac OS "System" used `TRAP` in a similar way, too, and the Amiga didn't use it at all.)

Comment: +1 for mentioning difference between Atari and Amiga OS calling schemes. :)

Comment: I only ever seem to remember using TRAP #11 at the end of all my code, back in the day (flite ftl-68k represent... sorry). I remember the tutor telling me that "it just returns control of the board to the OS"

Comment: Is a ```TRAP``` faster or slower than a ```JSR```? I imagine slower since it needs to enter supervisor mode.

Answer (score 4):

The 68000 provides 16 user traps (software interrupts/exceptions) but doesn't specify what they do. That is down to the system BIOS/OS, whether that be a simulator or Amiga, Atari ST etc. You can find a list of tasks performed by TRAP 15 in Easy68k at the bottom of this document http://www.easy68k.com/files/EASy68KQuickRef.pdf.